# Ion-tabs tabs-top on iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have an app that contain ion-tabs on top. It works fine on Android but with iOS the tabs are behind of header.

How could I solve this ?

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-top tabs-color-active-positive">

      <!-- Empresas Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Empresas" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/emp">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-emp"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Servicos Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Serviços" icon-off="ion-ios-people-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-people" href="#/tab/serv">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-serv"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Acessar Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Acessar" icon-off="ion-ios-world-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-world" href="#/tab/acesso" ng-click="isLogged();">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-acesso"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>


      <!-- Anunciantes Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Anunciar" icon-off="ion-ios-star-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-star" href="#/tab/anuncio">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-anuncio"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Info Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Informações" icon-off="ion-ios-information-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/info">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-info"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
```

[image]

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/943

Comment: try to add a top-margin to the tab